# Plot parametric curve of differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Can anyone help me to plot the parametric curve $(y(t),y'(t))$ of this differential equation:

$$y''+0.3\,y'-y+y^3=0.5 \cos⁡(1.2t),\,\,    y(0)=1,\,\,    y'(0)=0$$

Comment: Look up `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue` in the documentation to figure out how to solve the differential equation to get 'y[t]' and `y'[t]`, and then look up `ParametricPlot` in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

At least show some efforts.

Following the suggestions in the comment, we can have

```
ode = y''[t] + 0.3*y'[t] - y[t] + y[t]^3 == 0.5*Cos[1.2*t];
sol = NDSolve[{ode, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot[{y[t], y'[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]